# Como salvar um arquivo PDF no SQL Server 2008 usando C#

Tags: c#

A base de dados está preparada para guardar o PDF em um campo do tipo `VarBinary(MAX)`.

Como fazer a leitura deste campo posteriormente?

Comment: Porque você não salva dentro de uma pasta na raiz do seu sistema? Fica mais leve e mais fácil.

Answer (score 1):

**Você até pode faze-lo e irei ensinar como, porém gostaria de alertá-lo que esta não é uma boa pratica, o melhor a ser feito é salvar este arquivo no Servidor (de preferencia criptografado) e salvar apenas o caminho para ele no banco de Dados.**

Como você não especificou o formato da sua tabela, vou utilizar a seguinte:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[File](
    [FileGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Extension] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [CreationTime] [datetime2](2) NOT NULL,
    [LastAccessTime] [datetime2](2) NOT NULL,
    [LastWriteTime] [datetime2](2) NOT NULL,
    [Length] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [FileStream] [varbinary](max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_File] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FileGUID] ASC
)
```

Abaixo o modelo para a tabela acima

**Model**

```
public partial class File
{
    public System.Guid FileGUID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastAccessTime { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastWriteTime { get; set; }
    public long Length { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileStream { get; set; }
}
```

**Preenchendo o Modelo**

```
var sample = new FileInfo(@"D:\Sample.pdf");
if (sample.Exists) {
    var fileBinary = new byte[sample.Length];
    using (var fileStream = sample.OpenRead()) {
        fileStream.Read(fileBinary, 0, (int)sample.Length);
    }

    var fileName = sample.Name.Substring(0, sample.Name.Length - sample.Extension.Length);
    var fileExtension = sample.Extension.Substring(1);
    var fileSample = new File {
        FileGUID = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Name = fileName,
        Extension = fileExtension,
        CreationTime = sample.CreationTime,
        LastAccessTime = sample.LastAccessTime,
        LastWriteTime = sample.LastWriteTime,
        Length = sample.Length,
        FileStream = fileBinary
    };

    //Logica para inserir no Banco
}
```

Como você também não especificou a tecnologia que esta sendo utilizada no seu projeto, vou postar um exemplo de como salvar esta entidade no Banco usando Entity Framework e ADO.NET

**Entity Framework**

```
using (var context = new FileManagerEntities()) {
    context.Files.Add(fileSample);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**ADO.NET**

```
var sqlCommandString = @"
    INSERT INTO [File]
    VALUES (
        @FileGUID, 
        @Name, 
        @Extension, 
        @CreationTime, 
        @LastAccessTime, 
        @LastWriteTime, 
        @Length, 
        @FileStream
    );
";

var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted };
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions))
{
    var sqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FileManagerConn"].ConnectionString;
    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCommandString, sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@FileGUID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, 16).Value = fileSample.FileGUID;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = fileSample.Name;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Extension", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = fileSample.Extension;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@CreationTime", SqlDbType.DateTime2, 6).Value = fileSample.CreationTime;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@LastAccessTime", SqlDbType.DateTime2, 6).Value = fileSample.LastAccessTime;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@LastWriteTime", SqlDbType.DateTime2, 6).Value = fileSample.LastWriteTime;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Length", SqlDbType.BigInt, 8).Value = fileSample.Length;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@FileStream", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = fileSample.FileStream;
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Por fim a parte que realmente lhe interessa, ler o arquivo salvo anteriormente:

**Entity Framework**

```
var fileSample = default(File);
var fileGUID = new Guid("0C0281E5-0FCD-4324-B25A-77F5544CA106");

using (var context = new FileManagerEntities()) {
    fileSample = context.Files.Find(fileGUID);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**ADO.NET**

```
var fileSample = default(File);
var fileGUID = new Guid("0C0281E5-0FCD-4324-B25A-77F5544CA106");

var sqlCommandString = @"
    SELECT 
        FileGUID,
        Name,
        Extension,
        CreationTime,
        LastAccessTime,
        LastWriteTime,
        Length,
        FileStream
    FROM [File]
    WHERE FileGUID = @FileGUID
";

var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted };
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions))
{
    var sqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FileManagerConn"].ConnectionString;
    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCommandString, sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@FileGUID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, 16).Value = fileGUID;
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            using (var sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (sqlReader.HasRows)
                {
                    sqlReader.Read();
                    fileSample = new File();
                    fileSample.FileGUID = sqlReader.GetGuid(0);
                    fileSample.Name = sqlReader.GetString(1);
                    fileSample.Extension = sqlReader.GetString(2);
                    fileSample.CreationTime = sqlReader.GetDateTime(3);
                    fileSample.LastAccessTime = sqlReader.GetDateTime(4);
                    fileSample.LastWriteTime = sqlReader.GetDateTime(5);
                    fileSample.Length = sqlReader.GetInt64(6);
                    fileSample.FileStream = sqlReader.GetValue(7) as byte[];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Agora tudo que precisa é manipular os bytes em `fileSample.FileStream`, para isto pode usar um MemoryStream para enviar o arquivo atraves de um WebService ou um FileStream caso queira salvar o mesmo em disco.